# Apache SSL configuration error

Tags: java, apache, ssl

I am using apache `apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar` and `apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar` version 4.1 and follow this tutorial [here](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl), Its clear in the article that it support HttpClient < 4.3 but I am getting an syntax error in code.

here:

```
    1. SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(easyStrategy,SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    2. SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    3. registry.register(new Scheme("https", 8443, sf));
    4. ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(registry);
    5. client = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm);
```

in all of these it says the constructoe is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You've probably imported javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory instead of the Apache one.

Comment: All imports are okay `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`